# How include image in .jar file for exporting into .exe

Tags: image, jar, export, exe, viewer

i made this code:

```
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class ExplaneImage { 

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
       Image image = null;
        try {
            File sourceimage = new File
                    ("C:\\...\\ExplaneImage\\im1.jpg");
        image = ImageIO.read(sourceimage);
    } catch (IOException e) {}        

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(496, 325);
    JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
    frame.add(label);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

I'll need export this first in .jar file, after in .exe file (I have found the program to convert it), but it doesn't work cause exportation was made from class and not from a package, and the picture is not included in class.
I would like to make a simple images viewer for export in .exe format (to use on computers that do not have the jdk and jre) , independent, also containing images. 
Thanks a lot for your help